# Execution of dependent statement in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is two php statement:

```
1) $this->db->query($sql);
2) $this->db->query($sql2);
```

how to make sure that 2nd statement executes if only the first one executes?

I have tried like following but it doesn't work.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if($query != NULL) {
 $this->db->query($sql2);
}
```

Comment: It's so simple change `if($query != NULL)` to `if($query)`

Comment: What you mean "executes"? Has no errors? Returns results? Also, we have no idea what `this->db` is. Are you using a framework?

Comment: yes i am using a framework and it is codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if(!empty($query)) {
 $this->db->query($sql2);
}
```

Comment: `if($query)` could have been more sweet ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$count = count($query); 

if($count != 0) { //means if the first query returned some rows...
 $this->db->query($sql2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [**mysql_affected_rows**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) like

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    $this->db->query($sql2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this and it depends whether you wanna do it if the query ran successfully or whether it actually affected some rows

Method 1 (If the query failed, meaning it didn't run because of a syntax error)

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
If($query != false) $query2 = $this->db->query($sql2);
```

Method 2 (If the query affected one row or more, meaning it had no error but no rows matched its criteria)

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
If($query->affected_rows > 0) $query2 = $this->db->query($sql);
```